# ES6 arrow function returns undefined instead of desired value

Tags: javascript, optimization, ecmascript-6

Easy function that works in JS without ES6:

```
var evenOrOdd = function(n){
   if(n % 2 == 1){
      return "Odd";
   } else {
      return "Even";
   }
}

console.log(evenOrOdd(3)); //returns odd
```

My attempt at restructuring this using ES6:

```
const evenOrOdd = (n) => {(n % 2 == 1) ? "Odd" : "Even"};

console.log(evenOrOdd(3)); //returns undefined
```

I'm following these examples here: [2ality](http://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html) and [stoimen](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/02/07/javascript-optimization-optimizing-if-statements/).

Why is this arrow function returning `undefined`?

Comment: I also attempted replacing const with var and let (just to see) and nothing changed.

Comment: Remove the `{...}` around the function body. However, this has nothing to do with TCO because your function doesn't call another function.

Comment: oh, interesting. I thought TCO were the ? and : --I'm learning.  What's this called then? just optimization? and how do I give you "credit" for helping me?

Comment: `... ? ... : ...` is the [**conditional operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). TCO is something that the runtime can do if there is a *function call* in tail position (basically meaning that a function call is the last operation in another function). I.e. for TCO to happen one would have to refactor their code to put a function call in tail position. But that has nothing to do with the conditional operator specifically. And again, there cannot be any TCO because your function doesn't call another function.

Comment: TCO is something useful in the context of *recursive* functions. In your example, changing the code form an `if` statement to the condition operator is just "refactoring" the code.

Comment: awesome. I'll see if I can adjust the tags. Appreciate the help and information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `{}`.

```js
const evenOrOdd = n => (n % 2 === 1 ? "odd" : "even")

console.log(evenOrOdd(3)) //=> "odd"
```

Comment: Or explicitly add `return`.

Answer (score 0):

(It may help others)

I'm trying to return a value from nested function, which is wrong

```
const isEmailExistsInDb = usrEmail => {
    userModel.countDocuments( {"email": usrEmail}, function (err, count){
        return tempCount > 0;
    });
};
```

Correct one is, have to return value from parent function

```
const isEmailExistsInDb = usrEmail => {
    let tempCount;
    mongoModel.countDocuments( {"email": usrEmail}, function (err, count){
        tempCount = count;
    });
    // count > 0 if document exists
    return tempCount > 0;
};
```