# Could I get a little insight on why this returns undefined

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-operator

Could I get insight on why this returns undefined?

```
  let obj = {
    something:"ok"
}
  var i = 1;
  var b = 1;
  const testing = () => {
     i === b ? obj.something : "nothing"
}
   console.log(testing());
```

Comment: It throws a `ReferenceError`, `cool` is not defined

Comment: Because it is not defined

Comment: Please read the documentation on [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). `testing` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 arrow function returns undefined instead of desired value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852417/es6-arrow-function-returns-undefined-instead-of-desired-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no return statement in `testing`. Change to this and should work:

```
let obj = {
    something:"ok"
}

var i = 1;

var b = 1;


const testing = () => {
     return (i === b ? obj.something : "nothing");
}

console.log(testing());
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely blanked the square brackets.